# Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 throughput

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have an Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24) that is connected at 300mbit/s according to `iwconfig`. Using Windows 7 I get an average throughput of 11MB/s upload. On (K and X)ubuntu I only get 3 to 5 MB/s up. Connection is stable on 5GHz. I tested SCP and SMB.

Is there anyone out there who has an upload speed around 10MB/s using this card?

On 2.4GHz it shows connection dropouts when using a/n mode. However, I did not encounter this on windows (might also be I'm always on 5GHz in Windows)

[Here is a bug report on the dropouts using wlan n](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1159145). The bug is closed as it seems that often it is a hardware issue.

I wonder if it really is a hardware issue... Maybe I should try to get the card replaced by my notebooks manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

If it is an issue only with wireless N enabled wifi routers, this usually works

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

if `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` already has `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` you will need to edit the file manually with `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and change it, save and reboot

Comment: Thank you. I already knew about this. No changes to the issue whatsoever.

Comment: If you are seeing the fail to flush queue messages in dmesg, look at this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1270808