# What is the current state of Centrino Advanced-N 6235 on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, drivers, 17.10, intel-wireless

I'm running a Cirrus 7 with Ubuntu 17.10 with (unfortunately) comes with a Centrino Advanced-N 6235. This wireless adapter isn't working very well, it has a very slow reaction time and I can't get a throughput over 600 KB/S where other devices on the same network make easily up to 5 MB/s. I found several posts addressing this issue:

[Intel Centrino Centrino Advanced-N 6235 weak wireless reception](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398855)

[Lubuntu 13.10 Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev-24) issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370659)

[Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 throughput](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587571)

But they are old and mostly referring to an old Kernel bug, which seems to be fixed years ago:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1159145

So I am wondering if someone has this wireless adapter running without problems. Is this a hardware or a software issue, is there anything I could do to improve the connection?

Here is an example of the dsmg output (I changed the MAC address):

```
sudo dmesg | grep wlan0     
[233696.907293] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[233696.943294] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[233696.950553] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=3)
[233696.971412] wlan0: associated
[233697.148133] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[234303.411322] wlan0: deauthenticated from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[234306.669023] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[234306.671710] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[234306.740030] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[234306.741659] wlan0: authenticated
[234306.743528] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[234306.754636] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[234306.762087] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[234306.781035] wlan0: associated
[234306.833064] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[234963.247556] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[234977.040692] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[234977.446692] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[234977.742178] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[234983.631079] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[234983.633661] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[234983.647935] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[234983.649515] wlan0: authenticated
[234983.651185] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[234983.662128] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[234983.663729] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[234983.681553] wlan0: associated
[234983.681642] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[234983.741230] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[236621.605584] wlan0: authenticate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[236621.608725] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[236621.631390] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[236621.634509] wlan0: authenticated
[236621.636467] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[236621.672118] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[236621.677269] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
[236621.697238] wlan0: associated
[236622.018362] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[236631.185506] wlan0: deauthenticated from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[236634.316592] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[236634.319552] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[236634.436946] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[236634.446272] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 3/3)
[236634.447530] wlan0: authenticated
[236634.448951] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[236634.461017] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[236634.462678] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[236634.480750] wlan0: associated
[236634.539934] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[237344.790317] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[237344.792735] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[237344.805029] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[237344.908714] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 3/3)
[237344.916829] wlan0: authentication with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX timed out
[237348.565955] wlan0: authenticate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[237348.571036] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[237348.573630] wlan0: authenticated
[237348.576910] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[237348.611628] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[237348.616068] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
[237348.636020] wlan0: associated
[237348.646800] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[237355.786883] wlan0: deauthenticated from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[237359.024330] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[237359.027513] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[237359.037446] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[237359.038615] wlan0: authenticated
[237359.040669] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[237359.052525] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[237359.054652] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[237359.072555] wlan0: associated
[237359.132027] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[237739.358617] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[237753.219112] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[237753.624920] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[237753.888248] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[237759.917539] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[237759.920045] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[237759.938618] wlan0: authenticated
[237759.940713] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[237759.951878] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[237759.959327] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[237759.977302] wlan0: associated
[237759.977369] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[237760.039421] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[255142.566147] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[255155.687210] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[255156.085066] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[255156.181962] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[255162.095411] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[255162.097742] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[255162.124284] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[255162.125497] wlan0: authenticated
[255162.126288] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[255162.138552] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[255162.145925] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[255162.163629] wlan0: associated
[255162.163681] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[255162.217334] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[265911.077667] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[265923.912257] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[265924.314049] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[265924.371327] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[265930.268754] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[265930.271147] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[265930.284924] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[265930.286114] wlan0: authenticated
[265930.286534] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[265930.299044] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[265930.306503] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[265930.324717] wlan0: associated
[265930.325206] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[265930.378405] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[271013.727836] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[271026.951951] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[271027.357950] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[271027.410915] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[271033.366098] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[271033.368730] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[271033.395844] wlan0: authenticated
[271033.398253] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[271033.409441] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[271033.416957] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[271033.434932] wlan0: associated
[271033.435004] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[271033.497089] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[272762.239176] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[272775.666048] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[272776.067294] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[272776.117239] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[272838.239374] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[272838.241560] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[272838.272957] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[272838.275026] wlan0: authenticated
[272838.277163] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[272838.289537] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[272838.298572] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 3/3)
[272838.309708] wlan0: association with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX timed out
[272841.443464] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[272841.445794] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[272841.973571] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[272842.997646] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 3/3)
[272843.989754] wlan0: authentication with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX timed out
[272847.703152] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[272847.705736] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[272847.796103] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[272847.798085] wlan0: authenticated
[272847.802088] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[272847.813819] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[272847.821237] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[272847.839254] wlan0: associated
[272847.839329] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[272847.890330] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[274485.409701] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[274499.016437] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[274499.418745] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[274499.489509] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[274505.623403] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[274505.625906] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[274505.717769] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[274505.719480] wlan0: authenticated
[274505.722457] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[274505.734346] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[274505.741845] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[274505.760225] wlan0: associated
[274505.760296] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[274505.812735] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[276263.823953] wlan0: disconnect from AP XX:28:6d:30:13:XX for new auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[276263.864757] wlan0: authenticate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[276263.869263] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[276263.894125] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[276263.897166] wlan0: authenticated
[276263.897559] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[276263.939189] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[276263.943740] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
[276263.965093] wlan0: associated
[276263.992147] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[276624.641168] wlan0: disconnect from AP e0:28:6d:30:13:4c for new auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[276624.679870] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[276624.682694] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[276624.801930] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[276624.810914] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 3/3)
[276624.818445] wlan0: authentication with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX timed out
[276624.982863] wlan0: authenticate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[276624.994506] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[276625.108991] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[276625.131145] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 3/3)
[276625.138901] wlan0: authenticated
[276625.141010] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[276625.178807] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[276625.183263] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
[276625.203002] wlan0: associated
[276625.257311] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[276635.871049] wlan0: deauthenticated from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[276639.031276] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[276639.033974] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[276639.138661] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[276639.147762] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 3/3)
[276639.156383] wlan0: authentication with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX timed out
[276640.216800] wlan0: authenticate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[276640.219983] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[276640.239414] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[276640.242444] wlan0: authenticated
[276640.245338] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[276640.279651] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[276640.284378] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
[276640.304424] wlan0: associated
[276640.412464] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[277192.251810] wlan0: deauthenticating from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[277205.451169] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[277205.861206] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[277205.927044] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[277211.877521] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[277211.880213] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[277211.954629] wlan0: authenticated
[277211.957132] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[277211.968471] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[277211.975972] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[277211.994133] wlan0: associated
[277211.994208] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[277212.055356] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[278405.085021] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[278418.475479] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[278418.877821] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[278418.944418] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[278424.847326] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[278424.849750] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[278424.932183] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[278424.933381] wlan0: authenticated
[278424.935313] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[278424.947366] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[278424.948981] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[278424.967788] wlan0: associated
[278424.967863] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[278425.025466] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[279823.410777] wlan0: disconnect from AP XX:28:6d:30:13:XX for new auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[279823.458072] wlan0: authenticate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[279823.462374] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[279823.487570] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[279823.490366] wlan0: authenticated
[279823.493227] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[279823.528668] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[279823.536688] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
[279823.556683] wlan0: associated
[279823.565251] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[279835.932630] wlan0: deauthenticated from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[279836.240544] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[279836.245045] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[279836.318104] wlan0: authenticated
[279836.318548] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[279836.330566] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[279836.332309] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[279836.351027] wlan0: associated
[279836.418882] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[281949.920882] wlan0: deauthenticating from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[281962.774607] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[281963.176701] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[281963.229034] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[281969.161146] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[281969.163385] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[281969.238973] wlan0: authenticated
[281969.241502] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[281969.254120] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[281969.256021] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[281969.274146] wlan0: associated
[281969.274203] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[281969.339422] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[281995.444539] wlan0: disconnect from AP XX:28:6d:30:13:XX for new auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[281995.496295] wlan0: authenticate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[281995.499374] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[281995.523310] wlan0: send auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[281995.526364] wlan0: authenticated
[281995.529733] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 1/3)
[281995.570090] wlan0: associate with e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (try 2/3)
[281995.575111] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=3)
[281995.596125] wlan0: associated
[281995.672576] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by e0:28:6d:30:13:4c
[282357.921483] wlan0: disassociated from e0:28:6d:30:13:4c (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[282358.168335] wlan0: authenticate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
[282358.171174] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[282358.266305] wlan0: send auth to XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[282358.267972] wlan0: authenticated
[282358.269333] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 1/3)
[282358.281038] wlan0: associate with XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (try 2/3)
[282358.282662] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:28:6d:30:13:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[282358.300939] wlan0: associated
[282358.360851] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by XX:28:6d:30:13:XX
```

Answer (score 3):

> disconnect from AP XX:28:6d:30:13:XX for new auth to e0:28:6d:30:13:4c

It appears that you have two SSIDs with the same name and that your device is roaming among them looking for a better connection. Sounds like my old girlfriend!

I suspect that they are the 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz segments of your router. I suggest that you rename them to differentiate them. I suggest router2.4 and router5 or something similar. After all the changes I recommend, see which segment offers the best speed and stick to it.

Please check the wireless settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, be certain that you have the latest possible firmware; check:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware
```

We hope you have 1.169.3. If not, then open a terminal and do:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.3_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

After all these changes, reboot the router and the computer and tell us if there is any improvement.